# Tryin to sort a list by location showing closest first using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Currently the list is displaying the furthest away first.
Code:

```
$('#techassigned option').sort(function(x, y)<br />
  {return $(x).data("dist") < $(y).data("dist") ? -1 : 1;}
));
```

I appreciate any help I get. If I am not asking correctly or if I left out something, I do apologize. This is my first question here at S.O.

Comment: what's wrong with the above sort & what's you are getting?
can you pls explain with html?